# Edit a string in shell script and display it as an array

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, unix

Input:

```
1234-A1;1235-A2;2345-B1;5678-C2;2346-D5
```

Expected Output:

```
1234
1235
2345
5678
2346
```

Input shown is a user input. I want to store it in an array and do some operations to display as shown in 'Expected Output'

I have done it in perl, but want to achieve it in shell script. Please help in achieving this.

Comment: You should post what have you tried so far, see [ask]

Comment: Try this - 
`echo "1234-A1;1235-A2;2345-B1;5678-C2;2346-D5"|tr ';' '\n'|cut -d'-' -f1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split an input text to an array you can follow this technique:

```
IFS="[;-]" read -r -a arr <<< "1234-A1;1235-A2;2345-B1;5678-C2;2346-D5"
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
1234
A1
1235
A2  
2345
B1  
5678
C2  
2346
D5
```

If you want to keep only 1234,1234, etc as per your expected output you can either to use the corresponding array elements (0-2-4-etc) or to do something like this:

```
a="1234-A1;1235-A2;2345-B1;5678-C2;2346-D5"
IFS="[;]" read -r -a arr <<< "${a//-[A-Z][0-9]/}"   #or more generally <<< "${a//-??/}"
declare -p arr     #This asks bash to print the array for us
#Output
declare -a arr='([0]="1234" [1]="1235" [2]="2345" [3]="5678" [4]="2346")'
# Array can now be printed or used elsewhere in your script. Array counting starts from zero
```

Comment: Thanks, it works partially. Actually in the output i want only 1234, 1235 etc but not the sufix i.e. A1, A2, B1 etc..

Comment: Yes, i know - I just want to demonstrate how it is done in bash with IFS and read. See update

Comment: Thanks @George. The updated script gives me expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
awk -F'[-;]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i%2!=0) {print $i}}' f
1234
1235
2345
5678
2346
```

**OR**

```
echo "1234-A1;1235-A2;2345-B1;5678-C2;2346-D5"|tr ';' '\n'|cut -d'-' -f1
```

**OR**
As @George Vasiliou Suggested -

```
awk -F'[-;]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {print $i}}'f
```

If Data needs to store in Array and you are using gawk, try below -

```
awk -F'[;-]' -v k=1 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i !~ /[[:alpha:]]/) {a[k++]=$i}} END {
> PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
> for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' f
1 1234
2 1235
3 2345
4 5678
5 2346
```

> ```
>  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" used to print the data in
>  sorted order.
> ```

Comment: More simple : `awk -F'[-;]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {print $i}}' <<< "$a"`

Comment: But with awk you are not assigning an array - you are not splitting input text to an array - You just print something . This can not be used later in a script.

Comment: Still data can not be used outside awk. How you will print after awk finish the value 2345 - awk array element 3?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou -  If we need to use array @ multiple places in bash and number of arguments are less then your approach would be perfect.

Comment: It all depends of what OP wants to do. Your solution is good for just  printing, my approach is based on handling the data around in the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

@Yash:@try:

```
echo "1234-A1;1235-A2;2345-B1;5678-C2;2346-D5" | awk '{gsub(/-[[:alnum:]]+/,"");gsub(/;/,RS);print}'
```

Substituting all alpha bate, numbers with NULL, then substituting all semi colons to RS(record separator) which is a new line by default.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @George and @Vipin.

Based on your inputs the solution which best suites my environment is as under:

```
i=0
a="1234-A1;1235-A2;2345-B1;5678-C2;2346-D5"
IFS="[;]" read -r -a arr <<< "${a//-??/}"
#declare -p arr
for var in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo " var $((i++)) is : $var"  
done
```

Output:

```
 var 0 is : 1234
 var 1 is : 1235
 var 2 is : 2345
 var 3 is : 5678
 var 4 is : 2346
```